# Is cosmetic cyberware free?

Tags: the-sprawl

As part of the harm move (p. 42), the guide says the following:

> Some of the results of the harm move may look pretty brutal – lost body parts
>   and broken cyberware! – but remember that these can be replaced and repaired.
>   Does the character get a simple prosthetic replacement, a cybernetic enhancement,
>   or adapt to and accept the loss? In The Sprawl, prosthetic replacements are as
>   functional as the parts they replaced; they don’t count as cyberware for these moves.
>   Cosmetic cyberware is free.

I'm stuck on the meaning of the last sentence. Is it just making a distinction between prosthetic and cosmetic, so that you can't choose to destroy a purely cosmetic enhancement? Or does it mean that *any* cosmetic cyberware is free at any time? The cyberware chapter only talks about prosthetic and stat boosting cyberware, it doesn't mention cosmetic. And if cosmetics are free, does that mean free in terms of mechanics, or actually free for the character?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: Giving "cosmetic" alterations away for free won't hurt anything, but you can make the PCs pay a bit (1 or 2 cred) if that better fits the tone of your particular cyberpunk world.

---

## 1. At character creation: definitely free

[Here's the author's general philosophy, from a forum thread](http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/index.php?topic=6835.msg30311#msg30311):

> I've had players make full-body cyborgs or vat-grown bioroids entirely as fictional positioning/colour. Pieces of cyberware simply add specific mechanical effects which the player can use.

So you're on very firm ground thinking that prosthetic and cosmetic alterations that simply grant baseline human abilities don't count as cyberware. Describe your character however you want in character creation, as long as it fits your shared vision of what your cyberpunk world is about. (For instance, there's an example in the book of describing your Killer as an AI in a humanoid robot body.)

---

## 2. In play: depends on the feel you want for our cyberpunk world

What about prosthetics and cosmetic-only cyber-stuff you acquire in play? Is it free, or do you pay for it?

We can get some high-level guidance from the Agenda:

> » Make The Sprawl dirty, high-tech and excessive
>
> » Fill the character’s lives with action, intrigue and complication

Principles:

> » Chrome everything, then make it dirty
>
> » Ask questions and incorporate the answers
>
> » Be a fan of the characters

And Moves:

> » Use up their resources

So, keep these in mind. Our goal is to create interesting complications and make the cyberpunk world feel dynamic and real.

Now, let's look at the Assets chapter, especially "fair prices" on page 128.

- You can get "discreet medical services for life-threatening wounds" for 4 cred. ("A street doctor for gunshot wounds" costs 2.) It's reasonable to figure that replacement organs or run-of-the-mill prosthetic limbs are included in that fee. Stick with that.
- 1 cred buys "basic restricted gear from a fixer (sidearms, hunting weapons, ammo)" or "replacement parts for a cyberdeck." 2 cred buys "more complex, restricted gear from a fixer (grenades, assault weapons, legal drones, basic hacking programs)." A drone is a pretty fancy piece of kit, so I think it's reasonable to declare "cosmetic" cyberware (color-changing hair! holographic tattoos! little retractable vampire fangs because you LARP in your off hours!) can be acquired for 1 or 2 cred, at most.
- PCs in the Sprawl don't really spend any cred on most of their day-to-day needs. You can just have a basic burner PDA or a t-shirt or whatever without getting cred or the "hit the street" move involved. If the stuff in question is something affordable like that, it's reasonable to make it free.

How do you decide between those last two?

Charge them for cyberware if you want it to seem substantial — it marks the enhancement as a big deal to the character, something they had to seriously think about and maybe save up for, and probably out of reach for the average person on the street.

Making it "free," on the other hand, indicates that it's probably widely available to the general populace.

**If you've created a setting that's mired in industrial grime**, where even basic luxuries are out of reach for anyone who isn't corporate stooge, lean towards charging a bit for the cosmetic stuff — that way, you're spotlighting the specialness of PCs who pursue self-expression through that path. You'll get a slightly darker, slightly more desperate world.

**If you've got a setting where the cyberpunk world is full of chrome and neon**, and self-modification is a form of self-expression or baby-transhumanism, lean towards just handing it out for free — that way, PCs are more likely to treat it casually and get glamorous cyber-mods to match the culture they live in. You'll get a slightly shinier, slightly more teched-up world.

Either choice is valid. Neither will break your game. If you're not sure, follow the "ask questions" principle and ask the player whose character is most into cosmetic augmentation to define how available and affordable the technology really is in your campaign.